# How to read en dash (–) with PHP from CSV file

Tags: php, csv

I have a .CSV file that is being supplied to me via an API, So I don't have any control over the charset of that.

The file contain few columns which have en dash (–) in it, like

> Clinical Nurse I – RN – Orthopedics

So when I read the file using PHP it comes to me like this

> Clinical Nurse I � RN � Orthopedics

I have been PHP using

```
$array = array_map('str_getcsv', file('myfile.csv'));
```

How should this be read so that I don't loose en dash?

-------EDIT------

I have been able to remove any such special character like en dash or em dash using the code below. but was not able to get them displayed or converted into UTF-8 [ `&ndash;` ]

```
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Can you try UTF-8 encode !

Comment: Yes I already tried that on the page where the contents needs to be displayed.

Comment: Which browser you tried ?
Did you checked on chrom or firefox ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to remove any such special character like en dash or em dash using the code below. but was not able to get them displayed or converted into UTF-8 [ – ]

```
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, "UTF-8");
```